# Inserting based on the results of a select query

Tags: database

Initially I had all columns under 1 table. In table shown below had one additional column for all `media items`.

> did | disclaimer_title | disclaimer_body | disclaimer_media_items

But for some reasons, I need to pull out the `disclaimer_media_items` column into separate schema. **So now I have 2 tables**.

**Table 1 schema**

> did | disclaimer_title | disclaimer_body

**Table 2 structure:**

> did_media | disclaimer_media_items

Now what I want is when I insert media in table 2, the results get stored for table 1.

i.e. **I want to achieve same functionality of all columns under table 1 with two individual tables.**

I know 2 things can work, either `foreign key` or `Drupal joins`. How can I achieve this?

*Hope I explained it well.*

Answer (score 1):

[db_merge](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_merge/7) is the solution for this.

Comment: how did you implement this? post answer in detail.